# Converting whole number to hour and minute format

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have data extracted from a database where the time format do not have a semicolon in between.  Example 0810 should read as 8:10 and 1445 should read as 14:45.  I want to convert those data in hour and minute format and I should perform a calculation, e.g. getting the time difference between those two data.  Need help in the correct formatting formula.

Comment: No reason this should be getting a down vote =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Excel's [LEFT and RIGHT functions](https://support.office.com/client/functions-to-split-text-389f665d-ec1a-4271-9c5a-c35280be795d) to dissect the text into hours and minutes, and then use Excel's [TIME function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/time-function-HP010342955.aspx) to create an actual "time" object based on that.

Assuming *text* time as provided (0810, 1445, etc.) is in Cell A1:

> =TIME(LEFT(A1,2),RIGHT(A1,2),0)

*Note:* Double check the `format` of the original data is `text`, if the format is set to `general` the above formula will not work correctly.

This will produce a time according to your computers windows control panel regional default time format.  (in the USA, likely h:mm AM/PM).  If you need it in 24-hour, format the cells that contain the formula to use a Custom format set to "hh:mm".

The best practice if you have an entire column of data to convert would be at add a new blank column to the right of the data, ensure the original column format is `text`, use the formula above in the new column, and hide the original column.

Comment: Thought about editing, but I'm not sure the best way to efficiently add that OP should be putting the formula in another cell such as B1.  I would insert a blank column, use this formula there and then hide the original column.  (I wrote an answer like this not long ago and the OP tried to use the formula in the column holding the data.)

Comment: Feel free to edit it in, the more info the better. I kind of assumed the OP had basic Excel skills. ;)

Comment: I did also when I wrote my answer =] If no ones done it yet when I get off the conf call that I'm on, I'll take a stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a custom cell format:

1. Highlight the cells to format
2. Right click and select `Format cells...`
3. Select `Custom` at the bottom of the cell formatting tab
4. In the field to enter a custom format type `00\:00`
5. Click `OK`

Source: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/121/comment-page-1/

Comment: This might work.  It may also produce garbage.  It depends on what Excel thought the data type was before the custom format was created.

Comment: Converting the column to text or general first should work around that, but I didn't test. The problem comes when excel assumes on import that the string is a time when it's really a date, or a date when it's really a time.

Comment: I reproduced... setting the column to `text` first will ensure this works as expected.